# Android. User access to SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I was wondering if the user has access to the `SharedPreferences` in which I store some app data. I intend to do a very simple counter which counts the number of times the user uses a feature in my app and if the value passes a certain predefined one, then I block the access to that feature. I do not intend to use a server to keep track of every such counter on every device which uses my app, but I would prefer to store this data locally.

The question is how easily can the user access the `SharedPreferences` and remove the data I store, thus resetting the counter. Where exactly does the `SharedPreferences` get stored? Is it easy to access?

It is not THAT important if the user does manage to reset the counter, it is not a critical thing, but I'd prefer to implement a simple method to at least discourage or make it a bit harder for him/her to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharedPreferences are stored in the device as an XML file. Users won't have access to this unless the device is rooted.

Comment: I see. And if the device is rooted I'm guessing the user will have read/write permissions on the file, including removing it altogether? (I've never actually handled a rooted phone)